# How to do I access an array of structs using ONLY pointers

Tags: c, clang

I am trying to access the students array of structs and modify a "Student" at a given index (using a for loop).

However, I am trying to access it using only a pointer, not like this:

students[currStudent].theory = thoeryGrade;

But something along the lines of:

*(studentPtr + currStudent).practical = practicalGrade;

Note: The above  line doesn't compile.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Student
{
    double theory;
    double practical;
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student students[50];
    const int numStudents;
    int thoeryGrade, practicalGrade = 0;
    Student *studentPtr = students;

    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &numStudents);

    while (1)
    {
        for (int currStudent = 0; currStudent < numStudents; currStudent++)
        {
            printf("Enter theory average of student %d: ", (currStudent + 1));
            scanf("%d", &thoeryGrade);

            printf("Enter practical average of student %d: ", (currStudent + 1));
            scanf("%d", &practicalGrade);

            students[currStudent].theory = thoeryGrade;
            *(studentPtr + currStudent).practical = practicalGrade;
            printf("\n");
        }
        for (int currStudent = 0; currStudent < numStudents; currStudent++)
        {
            printf("Student # %d -> Theory: %.2f", (currStudent + 1), students[currStudent].theory);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Student # %d -> Practical %.2f", (currStudent + 1), students[currStudent].practical);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo

*(studentPtr + currStudent).practical = practicalGrade; doesn't actually work..

Comment: "*the above line doesn't compile*". And the error is what? Please consider what info people need to know when posting your question. Showing the exact error should be something obvious to show.

Comment: `(*(studentPtr + currStudent)).practical = practicalGrade;`?? Also `const int numStudents;` and `scanf("%d", &numStudents);` -- won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` operator has higher precedence than `*` (dereference), so you need to enclose the expression `*(studentPtr + currStudent)` in brackets.

```c
(*(studentPtr + currStudent)).practical = practicalGrade;
```

Alternatively, use the `->` operator to directly access a member on the pointer.

```c
(studentPtr + currStudent)->practical = practicalGrade;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code has issues.

You must be ignoring compiler warnings about `const` in the declaration of `const int numstudents`.

Why does the `scanf()` accept integers, then store the pair into doubles?

It may be safe(?) to disregard the 0th element of the array, and make the loops for input and printing:

```
for (int currStudent = 1; currStudent <= numStudents; currStudent++)
```

Then you wouldn't need the `currStudent+1` excess baggage.

The easiest way to condense the code is to use a temporary pointer inside the loop that points to the current student (array element).

```
for (int currStudent = 1; currStudent <= numStudents; currStudent++) {
    Student *pCur = &students[ currStudent ];
```

Then you can use `pCur->theory` and `pCur->practical` to copy or print.

Finally, "student" appears as all-or-part-of a datatype, an array name, a loop counter and text in a string. Perhaps the datatype could be renamed 'record' and the loop counter 'index'.